# parse json data already in an array?

Tags: java, json-simple

I have the following data:

```
[{"class":"test","description":"o hai","example":"a","banana":"b"}]
```

As this JSON data is already in an array, I'm having troubles to parse this with JSON simple:

```
File file = new File( "/Users/FLX/test.json");
String s = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);

Object obj = parser.parse(s);
JSONArray array = (JSONArray) obj;
log.warn("WAAAAT"+array.get(1));
```

This doesn't work because "1" (description) is in array 0, which causes an out of bounds exception, how can I properly do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[] denotes an array, while {} denotes an object, so you have an array of objects.

The way your JSON is formatted, you have an array which contains a single object.  That single object has properties named "class", "description", "example", and "banana" with values "test", "o hai", "a", and "b" respectively.

JSONArray is 0 based so `array.get(1)` would be out of bounds.  In order to get description you would do something like `array.getJSONObject(0).get("description")`

Comment: +1 or even better than calling array.getJSONObject(0), use array.getJSONObject( index ); where index is >= 0 and < array length

Comment: Agreed Dorin.  I kept it specific to his case in my example.